# How to retrieve the last tuple in a list then append a value to that tuple before returning it back to that list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list that looks like this:

```
receipt = [name,('beef','onion','mint')]
```

What I want to do is add a value to the last tuple in this list. I want to be able to do this multiple times when the list has multiple tuples in it. Each time only appending a value to the last tuple. 
So how do I make this become:

```
receipt = [name, ('beef','onion','mint','chile')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable so they cannot be modified, but they could be replaced with an updated tuple:

```
receipt[-1] = receipt[-1] + ('chile', )
```

Which yields:

```
['...', ('beef', 'onion', 'mint', 'chile')]
```